# What is the minimum amount which can be raised to after a bet and a raise in front?

Tags: cash-game, raise, bet-sizing

Last night in our 1/2 game we had this happen: first there was a bet of $3 and then I raised to $7. The next player raised to $11 and was told he had to bet at least $14.

Should he have been allowed to bet the $11? I still don't know what his minimum raise could have been.

Comment: A raise to $11 after a raise to $7 from $3 is valid. The min-raise is $4 since that was the amount of the previous raise (7 - 3), so a raise must go to at least 7 + 4 = $11.

Comment: I would highly recommend looking at some tutorials on bet sizing, these are not good bet sizes

Answer (score 5):

In most card rooms, the raise to $11 is perfectly valid.  Some have [pointed out here](https://poker.stackexchange.com/a/2816/1478) before, though, that some european poker rooms use a different convention where any raise must be double the last bet. In that case, the minimum would be $14.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, a raise is minimum 2x the amount raised. So to the $11 raiser, minimum raise would be:
$7 - $3 = $4 raise so he/she could call $7 or raise to a minimum of $7 + the raise, $4.

Comment: Yes $11 is there minimum raise under standard rules. Some rooms do have the more restrictive rule that a raise must double the current bet amount, making the minimum raise $14. This is non-standard, but such rooms do exist.