# Minimum Legal Re-raise before All in

Tags: rules

I posted a picture below for clarity.

- Blinds 100 / 200
- SB = posted 100 blinds
- BB = posted 200 blind
- UTG = Bet 400
- Low Jack = Raise 600
- High Jack = Goes for all in 900
- Cut off = 1,200

Is this correct a computation? 1,200 is the minimum legal amount of **re-raise** after all in?
Can someone explain it to me if I am wrong, and provide some resources like TD rules etc.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The rules differ between Limit and No Limit Hold'em.

In most No-Limit Hold'em games, the rules are as follows (BB = 'big blind'):

- The first pre-flop raise must be by 1 BB (i.e. to 2 BB or more).
- The first bet on any other street must be at least 1 BB.
- For other raises, **the minimum raise is the size of the last raise**.

For example, if the current bet is 300 and someone raises to 1300, that's a raise of 1000, so the next player (if raising) must raise to at least 2300.

(There are more complicated rules when a player goes all in with fewer chips than are required to meet the minimum raise, but those aren't relevant to the specific question asked.)

In your example:

- UTG makes the first pre-flop raise, so the minimum raise is 1 BB (200) for a total bet of 400. Minimum raise (MR) remains 200.
- LJ min-raises 200 to a total of 600. MR remains 200.
- HJ raises 300 to a total of 900. MR is now 300 (i.e. 900 - 600).
- CO min-raises 300 to a total of 1200.

The fact that HJ was all in is not relevant, because his raise exceeded the minimum raise at that point. As mentioned above, if HJ had fewer chips - say, 750 total - then he could still go all in for an "under-raise" of 150; what happens next is outside the scope of the question.

There are many resources online which cover this. See for example this [Betting in Poker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betting_in_poker#:%7E:text=Modern%20poker%20rules%20require) article or [this question](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/2729/what-is-the-min-raise-and-min-reraise-in-holdem-no-limit) and its associated links.

House rules may occasionally differ, but the above protocol is more or less universal.